# Entity Framework - How to create linking table with two indexes with inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework and ASP.NET identity. I have derived from IdentityUser and IdentityGroup to store extra fields for my application.

I want to call properties: User.Groups and Group.Users, a many-to-many relationship, and have EntityFramework automatically create the linking table, GroupUsers.

My first attempt had the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationGroup> Groups { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class ApplicationGroup : IdentityGroup<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationGroupRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityGroup<TUser, TKey> : IGroup<TKey>
    where TUser : IdentityUser
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual ICollection<TUser> Users { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

And the DBMigration looked something like

```
        CreateTable(
            "UMS.ApplicationGroupApplicationUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    ApplicationGroup_Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ApplicationGroup_Id, t.ApplicationUser_Id })
            .ForeignKey("UMS.ApplicationGroups", t => t.ApplicationGroup_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("UMS.Users", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationGroup_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id);
```

In particular, note the linking table has two indexes, one for each foreign key.

However, I wanted to name the linking table explicitly, so in my DBContext I added:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroup>().ToTable("Groups")
            .HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithMany(x => x.Groups)
            .Map(x =>
            {
              x.ToTable("GroupUsers");
              x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
              x.MapRightKey("GroupId");
            });
```

However, this gives me an automatic migration with only 1 index:

```
        CreateTable(
            "UMS.GroupUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    GroupId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.GroupId })
            .ForeignKey("UMS.Groups", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("UMS.Users", t => t.GroupId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);
```

Is this just a bug in EntityFramework? This appears to only happen when one type has a collection of the other via a derived type. Is it possible to keep an explicitly named linking table whilst automatically creating both indexes?

Answer (score 1):

This may not resolve the problem you are having, however, it will correct your code.  In your case, as per definition, the "Left Key" should be "GroupId" and the "Right Key" should be "UserId". [Check this link.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.manytomanyassociationmappingconfiguration.mapleftkey%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) Notice the code you posted, you have got them mixed:

.ForeignKey("**UMS.Groups**", t => t.**UserId**, cascadeDelete: true)
.ForeignKey("**UMS.Users**", t => t.**GroupId**, cascadeDelete: true)

Your code should look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroup>().ToTable("Groups")
        .HasMany(x => x.Users)
        .WithMany(x => x.Groups)
        .Map(x =>
        {
          x.ToTable("GroupUsers");
          x.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
          x.MapRightKey("UserId");
        });
```

Comment: Good spot - you're right. This doesn't solve the issue unfortunately, though.